# How do I read values from a dat file with six columns into another file?

Tags: shell-script, shell

So I have a file full of data for six different things in a different column:

```
1   0.020   0.700   5.4 1500    4000
2   0.020   0.700   5.4 1500    4050
3   0.020   0.700   5.4 1500    4100
4   0.020   0.700   5.4 1500    4150
5   0.020   0.700   5.4 1500    4200
```

I want to read values from the six columns into this second file that I currently have set up below. I was intending to use these as input to be read into a third file, "inlist_changer.sh" file. I apologize, but I am not very experienced with shell scripting so perhaps in addition to this, you may know a more effective way for me to not even repeat the interchanging `bash` and `EOT` commands.

```
bash inlist_changer.sh<<EOT
placeholder_value1
EOT
bash inlist_changer.sh<<EOT
placeholder_value2
EOT
bash inlist_changer.sh<<EOT
placeholder_value3
EOT
bash inlist_changer.sh<<EOT
placeholder_value4
EOT
bash inlist_changer.sh<<EOT
placeholder_value5
EOT
bash inlist_changer.sh<<EOT
placeholder_value6
EOT
./mk
./rn
bash inlist_changer.sh<<EOT
placeholder_value1
EOT
bash inlist_changer.sh<<EOT
placeholder_value2
EOT
bash inlist_changer.sh<<EOT
placeholder_value3
EOT
bash inlist_changer.sh<<EOT
placeholder_value4
EOT
bash inlist_changer.sh<<EOT
placeholder_value5
EOT
bash inlist_changer.sh<<EOT
placeholder_value6
EOT
./rn
bash inlist_changer.sh<<EOT
placeholder_value1
EOT
bash inlist_changer.sh<<EOT
placeholder_value2
EOT
bash inlist_changer.sh<<EOT
placeholder_value3
EOT
bash inlist_changer.sh<<EOT
placeholder_value4
EOT
bash inlist_changer.sh<<EOT
placeholder_value5
EOT
bash inlist_changer.sh<<EOT
placeholder_value6
EOT
./rn
```

Answer (score 0):

So let's say the first file with the six columns inputs is named "analysis.dat". Would I modify my second file like so? Note that I would like to call a script for each row in the input file.

```
while read -ra fields; do
    for field in "${fields[@]}"; do
        bash inlist_changer.sh <<<"$field"
    done
    ./mk
    ./rn
done < analysis.dat
```

Comment: @glenn jackman WHat does the last line mean by the way? Why is my first file's name at the end of the while loop?